# How to pass href value to below href

Tags: jquery

I have below html code in my aspx.

```
<input type="hidden" id="medicalLink" value='<a href="/forms/contactus.aspx" >Contact Us</a>' />
```

I want to pass complete href value of above input type to my below code when page gets rendered.

```
<div class="label" id="lblMedicalLink">
                    Medical and Travel insurance?:
                    <a href="#">Click</a>

                    <span class="asterisk" title="This field is mandatory">*</span></div>
```

After the page gets rendered, it will be show below code:

```
<div class="label" id="lblMedicalLink">
                    Medical and Travel insurance?:
                    <a href="/forms/contactus.aspx">Click Here</a>

                    <span class="asterisk" title="This field is mandatory">*</span></div>
```

I would appreciate if I can get answer in Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#anchToReplace").replaceWith($("#medicalLink").val());
});
```

I added an id [anchToReplace] to the anchor tag.

Hope this helps.